# How to make an RCP application run on Docker

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-che

I need to run my Eclipse RCP application on docker.

Is it possible to do it by contributing plugins to eclipse che or some other way around? Please suggest

Comment: you may have a look at a (old) thing called GTK Broadway e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/wsskeleton/eclipse-broadway / https://github.com/ws-skeleton/eclipse-broadway that may get some new traction with GTK4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned as comment by @christian-dietrich, just clone https://github.com/ws-skeleton/eclipse-broadway/ , replace https://github.com/ws-skeleton/eclipse-broadway/blob/master/Dockerfile#L45 by your product-specific things, if necessary, tweak https://github.com/ws-skeleton/eclipse-broadway/blob/master/init.sh#L21 as well, and there you are, you've got your Eclipse RCP application running over HTML browser in a docker container.

Once you have a docker image ready to use, you can make an Eclipse Che plugin for it, see https://github.com/eclipse/che-plugin-registry/blob/master/v3/plugins/ws-skeleton/eclipseide/4.9.0/meta.yaml for example of how Eclipse IDE over GTK/Broadway is made available in Eclipse Che.

If you use Che7 and the default Eclipse Che plugin registry (for example, if you use che.openshift.io), you can see the Eclipse IDE available as editor for your workspace. It does reuse all the stuff mentioned above and gives you an idea of the result.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a good point to start:

Documentation how to customize Eclipse Che environment:

- https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/developing-che-theia-plug-ins/
- https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/using-a-visual-studio-code-extension-in-che/

Mattermost channel to ask question:

- https://mattermost.eclipse.org/eclipse/channels/eclipse-che